# visual studio 2010, how to access a code snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I have used code snippets in VS 2005, VS 2008 like: `{code snippet},{TAB},{TAB}`. Since I migrated to VS 2010 I cannot use the 2 TAB combination anymore. How can I access it? I feel like a real noob :)

Edit:
I guess it works, but not for all of them... I tried for the `get` and didn't do anything. Maybe I should check what is with the `get` inside code-snippet manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination is still the way to insert code snippets in Visual Studio 2010.  It's likely another setting which is breaking this behavior.  I would try reseting my Visual Studio settings and see if that fixes the issue

- Tools -> Import / Export settings
- Navigate through the wizard
- Use the profile of your choice

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply... I went through the wizard and in the last step, there is "Choose a Default Collection of settings". Do I just need to pick one, does it matter really?

Comment: @Cristi if you don't know then choose "General"

Comment: Thanks Jared, actually I noticed something strange on my side... as I have a 'get' keyword as snippet, but no definition in Code-Snippet Manager under 'Visual-C#' where I was trying to use it. That's why I think I had problems. No clue where does this 'get' come from.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same combination as before (tab-tab works for me!).  It may be worth checking for any extensions you've installed that might override shortcuts...